# How to print out the position of a value of an array?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, max, min

```
int smallest = array[0];
int pos = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    if (array[x] < smallest) smallest = array[x];
    pos = x;
}

printf ("%d is the smallest number and its located in %d\n", smallest, pos);
printf ("\n");

int largest = array[10];
int position = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    if (array[y] > largest) largest = array[y];
    position = y;
}

printf ("%d is the largest number and its located in %d\n", largest, position);
```

What I have tried here doesn't work, when I compile and run it gives me the position 9 for both the largest and smallest array every time.

Comment: Provide a minimal complete program. This assignment int largest = array[10]; invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization in this declaration

```
int largest = array[10];
```

invokes undefined behavior provided that the array has 10 elements.

Also in this if statement

```
    if (array[x] < smallest) smallest = array[x];
        pos = x;
```

you need to use either the compound statement like

```
    if (array[x] < smallest)
    {
        smallest = array[x];
        pos = x;
    }
```

or the comma operator like

```
    if (array[x] < smallest) smallest = array[x], pos = x;
```

A general approach is the following.

```
size_t pos = 0;

for ( size_t i = 1; i < sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array ); i++ )
{
    if ( array[i] < array[pos] ) pos = i;
}

printf("%d is the smallest number and its located in %zu\n", array[pos], pos);

pos = 0;

for ( size_t i = 1; i < sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array ); i++) 
{
    if ( array[pos] < array[i] ) pos = i;
}

printf( "%d is the largest number and its located in %zu\n", array[pos], pos );
```

You can combine the two for loops in one for loop defining two variables for storing positions. For example

```
size_t pos_min = 0, pos_max = 0;

for ( size_t i = 1; i < sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array ); i++) 
{
    if ( array[i] < array[pos_min] ) pos_min = i;
    else if ( array[pos_max] < array[i] ) pos_max = i;
}
```

Thus `array[pos_min]` represents the minimum element and `array[pos_max]` represents the maximum element.

Comment: not good . real thing is     `smallest = array[x] < smallest ? array[pos = x] : smallest`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин This is a less readable code.

Comment: if you mention comma haha

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин I showed ways how the if statement can be rewritten to make it at least correct.